# setLeadComponet leading to a sluggish UI

Tags: codenameone

I have noticed that all my `setLeadComponent` calls are leading to a sluggish UI when scrolling up or down. It used to work perfectly in the past so I guess a recent platform update may have messed it up.

My use case requires me to create a list of items that users can scroll through and click on items. I have adopted the approach discussed in the 'Avoiding Lists' [article](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/avoiding-lists.html).

Any pointers on what may be causing this?

PS: I am currently exploring using `addPointerReleasedListener()` as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a couple of things described by these two issues. First it could be similar to the bug described [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3079).

It also could be due to [this](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2936), which was eventually resolved via by disabling layout on paint (which is now the default). It might make sense to re-enable layout on paint in the parent form to see if this solves your issue.

Comment: Much appreciated. I have managed to get addPointerReleasedListener() working as well - UI is way smoother than before. Rather tedious as it has to be applied to each component in the container.

I will explore the options given and share feedback.